# div se remueve del render al refrescar pagina Reacj js - HOOKS

Tags: reactjs

Saludos estimados por favor su apoyo y ayuda en si estoy construyendo bien esta lógica de rende-rizado, dejo los códigos si me puede indicar que esta faltando o por que sucede.

por localstorage obtengo un valor o string : SEGUROS DIRECTOS.

dentro de esta estructura viene el string : company.bussinessName: "SEGUROS DIRECTOS"

en el cual solo cuando este valor se cumpla debe mostrar un div con una información al ingresar lo realiza sin problemas la primera vez, pero si recargo la pagina o f5 ese div se remueve del render, return. dejo lo que tengo a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const InitialStep = (props) => {
  const { company } = getCurrentUserFromLocalStorage();

  const [userMKT, setuserMKT] = useState(company.bussinessName);

  useEffect(() => {
    setuserMKT(userMKT);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Form className="form" name="start-vehicular-quote">
        {userMKT === "SEGUROS DIRECTOS" ? (
          <div className="form-field">
            <div className="aem-Grid aem-Grid--12 selectInput">
              <div className="aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--3 aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--phone--4">
                <InputSelect
                  value={typeOptions}
                  className="nDocumentSelect"
                  name="tipoDocumento"
                  id={"tipoDocumento"}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setTypeoptions(e);
                  }}
                  options={stateOptions}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--9 aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--phone--8">
                <Input
                  label="Número de Documento"
                  className="numero_documento"
                  name="numdocumentoinput"
                  value={numdocumentoinput}
                  id={"numdocumentoinput"}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setNumdocumentoinput(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  type="text"
                  maxLength={
                    (typeOptions.value === 2 && 8) ||
                    (typeOptions.value === 1 && 11) ||
                    (typeOptions.value === 4 && 12)
                  }
                  regex={
                    (typeOptions.value === 2 && "^[0-9]+$") ||
                    (typeOptions.value === 1 && "^[0-9]+$") ||
                    (typeOptions.value === 4 && "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
                  }
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <div className="form-field">
          <button
            disabled={hasErrors}
            className={`button btn-red btn-normal`}
            role="button"
            onClick={handlerSubmit}
          >
            {vehiculoCaracteristicasObtenerRedux.onLoading ? (
              <div id="circle3"></div>
            ) : (
              author.stepZero.buttonText
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default InitialStep;
```

Comment: dices que la primera vez si funciona, cuando recargas `userMKT` si tiene  el valor "SEGUROS DIRECTOS"?

Comment: el valor se obtiene de un usuario especifico, si ese usuario tiene ese valor SEGUROS DIRECTOS. el div con los datos se le muestran, cuando ingresa la primera vez se muestra sin problemas, cuando recargas la pagina o f5 el div desaparece del render, o HTML, en la ternaria donde se crea y se iguala, no se por que se remueve al recargar. se entiende?

Comment: Revisaste que al actualizar la pagina el `localStorage` no se este eliminando?

Comment: Imagina que eres un usuario que tienes ese valor y al ingresar o hacer login, te muestro ese campo condicionado, cuando ingresaste lo puedes ver sin problemas, ahora si se te ocurre dar F5 o recargar la pagina ese campo se desaparece del render o HTML, eso esta pasando, no se el motivo?

Comment: Primero aclárame un duda , la construcción del hook y la ternaria están bien realizadas?, el valor SEGUROS DIRECTOS, siempre esta activo en la session del usuario en el loclastorage. ya lo revise, te voy a dejar una imagen, yo guardo ese valor en una constante userMKT y lo utilizo para condicionar la ternaria y mostrar el campo una vez detecte ese valor.

Comment: creo que ese `useEffect` esta de mas, ya que al hace esto: `useState(company.bussinessName);` le asignas ese valor a `useMKT`, borralo para ver que pasa

Comment: Ambos los veo correctos, el problema pasa es que en algun momento al refrescar la pagina estas eliminado el valor de tu localStorage, cosa que no debería suceder (tengo entendido), a menos que en la configuración de tu browser hayas específicado de alguna manera que al actualizar elimine todo tipo de almacenamiento. Yo utilizo el mismo método para guardar valores y me funcione sin problema, aun actualizando la página

Comment: ok lo puedo borrar pero eso puede ser motivo para que remueva el div condicionado?

Comment: Es una opción, ya que en el useEffect estas reasignando el valor de `userMKT`. Haz la prueba que te recomienda @Isaac

Comment: ok estoy probando estoy enviando un cambio para ver si soluciona el tema voy avisando..

Comment: si en teoría declarando en el state ya se había solucionado, el useEffect solo lo declaraba de nuevo pero no hacia ninguna función adicional lo retire y listo, no se reflejaba el cambio por un tema de cache, en el despliegue, solo basto declararlo en el stage y listo, Gracias por los consejos.